# Does every virtually cyclic group $G$ have the form $G=H\ltimes N$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

A **virtually cyclic group** is a group that has a cyclic subgroup of finite index. Every virtually cyclic group in fact has a normal cyclic subgroup of finite index (namely, the core of any cyclic subgroup of finite index), and virtually cyclic groups are therefore also known as cyclic-by-finite groups.

**My Question:** Let $G=H\ltimes N$, where $H$ is a finite subgroup and $N$ is a normal cyclic subgroup. Then $G$ is a virtually cyclic group. Does every virtually cyclic group $G$ have the form $G=H\ltimes N$, where $H$ is a finite subgroup and $N$ is a normal cyclic subgroup?

**What I've tried:** ‎Let $G$ be a virtually cyclic group. If ‎$‎‎G$ ‎is ‎finite, ‎then ‎the ‎proof ‎trivially ‎holds. ‎So ‎let's ‎suppose ‎‎$‎‎G$ ‎is ‎infinite.‎   Then $G$ contains an infinite cyclic subgroup $N$ of finite index. So b‎y ‎Lemma 11.4 from *3-manifolds* by J. Hempel, ‎‎$‎‎G$ ‎contains a‎ ‎finit‎e normal subgroup ‎$‎‎H$ ‎with ‎‎$‎‎G/H$ ‎isomorphic ‎to ‎either ‎‎$‎‎‎\mathbb{Z}‎$ ‎or ‎‎$‎‎‎\mathbb{Z}_2 * ‎\mathbb{Z}_2‎‎$. If $G/H\cong \mathbb{Z}$, then by considering ‎the ‎short ‎exact ‎sequence ‎‎$H‎\rightarrowtail ‎G‎\twoheadrightarrow‎‎ G/H$ ‎with ‎‎$‎‎G/H$ ‎free, ‎we ‎have‎ ‎‎$‎‎G= H\rtimes G/H$.‎

But I don't know what to do about $G/H\cong \mathbb{Z}_2 * ‎\mathbb{Z}_2(\cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \ltimes \mathbb{Z})$.

My another problem is that $N=G/H$ here is not normal in $G$ (As I mentioned in my question).

Comment: Let $N$ be a normal cyclic subgroup of finite index. Start by considering $C_G(N)$.

Comment: Please share your thoughts on the problem. Yet again, you have not provided any context . . .

Comment: @Shaun Sure. I'll add what I've tried. Thanks very much.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thanks for the comment. You mean the answer to my question is yes? What I need to prove is $G=N\rtimes C_G (N)$?

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you so much for the hint. I'm trying to present an argument by using your hint.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm trying to show that $G=C_G (N)'\ltimes N$, i.e. $G=C_G (N)'N$ and $C_G (N)'\cap N=1$. To do this, let $N=\langle a\rangle $. Consider $g\in G$. How can I find an element $x\in C_G (N)'$ such that $g=xa^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Unfortunately I couldn't prove that $G=N\rtimes C_G (N)'$. I was wondering if you could help me about that.

Comment: If $G$ is abelian but not cyclic then $C_G(N)=G$, and $C_G(N)'=1$, so you will not be able to prove what you are claiming.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven That's true. So how can I find a finite subgroup $H$ by which $G=H\ltimes N$?

Comment: Could you please at least tell me what $H$ is here so that I can prove $G=H\ltimes N$? I really have no idea about $H$. As @DavidA.Craven mentioned, I can't consider $C_G (N)'$ as $H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks very much for your comments. I've just added the answer by your hints. Is that right? I have just a few questions. Why do we have $|G:C_G (N)|\leq 2$? Why $H$ is normal in $G$ and $G/H$ is infinite dihedral?

Comment: I am sorry if my comments have been confusing, but I did not at any stage say that the answer to your question is yes. Note that your semidirect product is the wrong way round in your attempt.

Comment: @DerekHolt No problem. Thanks very much for your help. Does  the other way round hold? I mean does every virtually cyclic group has the form $G=H\rtimes N$ for a finite normal subgroup and a cyclic subgroup $N$?

Comment: @DerekHolt As I said in **what I've tried**, my only problem is about infinite dihedral group which is not free group to split the short exact sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a virtually cyclic group. By definition, $G$ contains a cyclic normal subgroup $N$ of finite index. Since $|G:N|<\infty$, we have that $|C_G (N):Z(C_G (N))|<\infty$. So by a result of Schur (if $Z(G)$ is of finite index in $G$, then the derived subgroup of $G$ is finite), $C_G (N)'$ is finite. Since $G/C_G (N)$ embeds in ${\rm Aut}(N)$ which has order $2$, we have either $C_G (N)=G$ or $|G:C_G (N)|=2$. We consider two following cases:

First case: Let $G=C_G (N)$. Since $G/G'$ is an abelian group with at most one infinite cyclic factor, it has a finite subgroup $H/G'$ with $G/H$ trivial or infinite cyclic. If $G/H$ is trivial, then $G$ is the semidirect product of $H$ and $1$. Otherwise, $G$ is the semidirect product of $H$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ (because the short exact sequence $1\to H\to G\to G/H \to 1$ splits by the fact that $G/H\cong \mathbb{Z}$).

Second case: Let $|G:C_G (N)|=2$. Then $H$ is normal in $G$ and $G/H$ is infinite dihedral. Since the short exact sequence $1\to H\to G\to G/H \to 1$ splits, then $$G=H\ltimes G/H\cong H\ltimes (\mathbb{Z}_2\ltimes \mathbb{Z})\cong (H\ltimes \mathbb{Z}_2)\ltimes \mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: Please specify the result of Schur.

Comment: Dear @Shaun I've just added it.

Comment: Thank you, @M.Ramana :)

Comment: @Shaun Your welcome. I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1):

No. A counterexample is the group defined by the presentation
$$\langle x,y,z \mid x^2=y^2=1, yz=zy, xy=yx,  xz=zxy \rangle.$$

This group is virtually cyclic, with infinite cyclic subgroup $N =\langle z \rangle$ of index $4$, but $N$ is not normal in $G$. The subgroup $\langle z^2 \rangle$ is normal but has no complement.

This group is a semidirect product $\langle x,y \rangle \rtimes N$, but that's the other way round.

Comment: I appreciate that. Dear @DerekHolt , is it true that every virtually cyclic group $G$ of the form $H\rtimes G$ for a finite normal subgroup $H$ and a cyclic subgroup $N$?